# Replacing missing values if lag and lead are the same

Tags: python, pandas, missing-data

I have yearly data. Each of these years is stored in a separate data frame. 
Some information is missing in some years, but may be available in other years. I can only trust the information if it is observed before and after the missing year.
e.g.:

```
Index     Identifier      Date      Owner
 1           A             2005       F
 2           A             2006       NaN
 3           A             2007       F
 4           B             2005       G
 5           B             2006       NaN
 6           B             2007       NaN
 7           B             2008       G
 8           B             2009       NaN
 9           B             2010       F
 10          C             2006       H
 11          C             2007       NaN
 12          C             2008       NaN
```

This should in the end look like :

```
 Index     Identifier      Date      Owner
 1           A             2005       F
 2           A             2006       F
 3           A             2007       F
 4           B             2005       G
 5           B             2006       G
 6           B             2007       G
 7           B             2008       G
 8           B             2009       NaN
 9           B             2010       F
 10          C             2006       H
 11          C             2007       NaN
 12          C             2008       NaN
```

So only if I observe the same before and after the missing year should there be a change. If I don't observe anything after, or if I observe something different I should not have a change. 
The real data is about 10 million observations per year. So a loop would be highly inefficient.

My current solution is:

```
framestot=(df2005, df2006, df2007, df2008, df2009, df2010)
df=pd.concat(framestot, ignore_index=True)
df=df.sort(columns='date', ascending=True, kind='quicksort')
df['lag'] = df.Owner 
df['lead'] = df.Owner
df['lag'] = df.groupby(['Identifier'])['lag'].transform(lambda grp: grp.fillna(method='ffill'))      
df['lead'] = df.groupby(['Identifier'])['lead'].transform(lambda grp: grp.fillna(method='bfill'))
df.loc[df['Owner'].isnull() & df['lead'] == df['lag'],'Owner'] = df.lag
```

This seems a very inefficient way to work around it. Is there a way to directly call this information ? 
If I am not mistaken this also takes whatever is the first non missing lag and lead. Can I restrict this ? For instance if I only want to replace if in the last two years and in the next two years they are the same. If the data is from more than two years ago I keep the missing value instead.

Comment: There is a `limit` param for `fillna` so you can pass `limit=2` if you want to limit the fill methods

Comment: Thanks, that definitely solves the second problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy solution, though not particularly efficient is to compare forward filling and backwards filling:

```
In [11]: df['Owner'].ffill()
Out[11]:
0     F
1     F
2     F
3     G
4     G
5     G
6     G
7     G
8     F
9     H
10    H
11    H
Name: Owner, dtype: object

In [12]: ff = df['Owner'].ffill()

In [13]: ff[ff == df['Owner'].bfill()]
Out[13]:
0    F
1    F
2    F
3    G
4    G
5    G
6    G
8    F
9    H
Name: Owner, dtype: object
```

and splice back in these to the original column:

```
In [14]: df['Owner'] = ff[ff == df['Owner'].bfill()]

In [15]: df
Out[15]:
    Index Identifier  Date Owner
0       1          A  2005     F
1       2          A  2006     F
2       3          A  2007     F
3       4          B  2005     G
4       5          B  2006     G
5       6          B  2007     G
6       7          B  2008     G
7       8          B  2009   NaN
8       9          B  2010     F
9      10          C  2006     H
10     11          C  2007   NaN
11     12          C  2008   NaN
```